# Missing artist's artwork in iTunes

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, mac, apple-music

I last iTunes Apple have changed algorithm of displaying picture for Artist. How does it works? Why almost all my Artist's doesn't have artwork?

[image]

As I see Alice Cooper have the image:

[image]

But why I can't see it in my list?

*Update:* As I see I can not perform "Show in Apple Music" for this artists. Can it be related with that fact that I have created my own album (Collection) for this artist?

Comment: the art work is for that album, if you've created your own, then obviously, the albums art work will not be put onto yours...

Comment: i have asked about artist artwork, not the album artwork. look at my pucture - I have artwork for album (this is not problem), but I have not art for artist

Comment: I'm assuming this is music you bought via iTunes?  If this music was taken from a CD, Apple will not believe that you legitimately bought this music. and quite rightly so.

Comment: No, but I have subsciption Apple Music and Apple Match. And part of artists (Alice in Chains, for example) doesn't have this problem.

Comment: this is something different, but worth a try, select all the effected artists, file -  library -  get album artwork.

Comment: This is such an annoying problem. Of the 94 artists in my iTunes, *four* have a picture. Ones that don't have pictures include the likes of Coldplay, Muse, Fall Out Boy, Queen, and the Beach Boys.

I've tried "Get album artwork" to no avail, and "Share details about your library with Apple" is enabled. I don't have an Apple Music subscription, if that's relevant...

Comment: @OzzieSpin You are assuming Apple is in-the-right by assuming music obtained from other sources is acquired illegitimately? Ever heard of Amazon, et. all?

Comment: It is the case - google.

Comment: There is a 21 page thread on Apple forums regarding this issue, so i doubt there is a solution until Apple *maybe* fixes it in the next iTunes update

Answer (score -2):

For me it shows only artwork for .m4a files. All the artist I have in mp3 format doesn't show artwork image.